# Angular 2 innerHtml, I want to add a button dynamically but it converts into text?

Tags: angular, typescript, innerhtml

In [Test Project](https://plnkr.co/edit/HHA4kt?p=info) you can see
I need a next button and event but it converts into simple text.

```
public watchedItems2: {data:Array<any>,res:string} = {"data":[],"res":"<button>Next</button>"};
```

Comment: In Angular, and most other modern web frameworks, we no longer treat HTML as strings to be inserted in the DOM. Put the button in your template and hide or show it as necessary.

Comment: is there any type of possibility?

Comment: Yes, there is: transfer data, not html. Let the template deal with generating HTML.